# Inductive relations: Explicit proof that inverse relation is refl

Tags: agda

In PLFA they define the inverse relation:

```
inv-z≤n :   ∀ {m : ℕ} 
            → m ≤ zero 
        ----------------------
            → m ≡ zero
```

And then assert that:

```
inv-z≤n z≤n = refl
```

My question is, how could I give an explicit proof of **m ≡ zero**? I'm looking something that looks like this:

```
inv-z≤n {m} (z≤n) = 
    begin
        m
    ≡⟨⟩
        .....
    ≡⟨⟩
        zero
    ∎
```

but completing the intermediate steps with something. Of course simply writing

```
inv-z≤n {m} (z≤n) = 
    begin
        m
    ≡⟨⟩
        zero
    ∎
```

compiles, but I don't find it satisfying. I want to know *why* **m ≡ zero** instead of just writing that **refl** is a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Matematiflo's answer is pretty comprehensive (and the gist of my more long-winded account below is already present in their first line of explanation), but intuitively/informally one can gain confidence in the unimpeachable formality of the Agda by thinking out loud as follows (and learning to do so whenever faced with a formal proof that seems hard to understand: leave the machine behind and 'reckon it out' in your own mind):

- if `m ≤ zero` holds (by hypothesis), then how could that be?
- `_≤_` is inductively defined, so there are two possibilities, corresponding to the 'base' and 'step' cases of that inductive definition:

  - in the first, `m` is/must be *definitionally equal to* `zero` (via the `z≤n` constructor, with its argument `n` then also equal to `zero`);
  - in the second, the `s≤s` constructor expects the RHS term to be of the form `suc n`, but that's impossible, because `zero` is not of that form... so there is no case to answer.
- so we must be in the first case... and now we are done, because the problem statement is (definitionally equal to) `zero ≡ zero`, which has `refl` as a proof of it.

In terms of your Agda fragment

```
inv-z≤n {m} (z≤n) = 
    begin
        m
    ≡⟨⟩
        zero
    ∎
```

what 'is going on' is that the pattern `(z≤n)` is actually *forcing* the prior binding `{m}` in fact to be of the form `{m@zero}` or `{m = zero}`... in the Good Old Days, such 'forced' bindings were marked with a dot (and interactively such bindings, and marks on bindings, would be inserted by the typechecker), so that the following would typecheck

```
inv-z≤n {.zero} (z≤n) = 
    begin
        zero
    ≡⟨⟩
        zero
    ∎
```

but the `@`-pattern or telescopic `{m = ...}` forms work just as well. But just because the typechecker accepts it doesn't really answer the question as to *why?*, does it?

There's maybe the additional meta-level *why?* as to "why is such reasoning sound in the first place?" which touches on our willingness to accept proof by induction on complicated inductive definitions, and the justification of dependently-typed pattern-matching as a mechanism to instrument such reasoning (and unification along with it as the means by which we can say what form(s) `m` must take in the course of such reasoning)... but

- that (perhaps) takes us too philosophically far off-topic, but is always part of the justification for type theory, and how we come to have confidence in such arguments, as well as the distinguished role played by definitional equality 'in the background';
- we are already working in an implementation of type theory, so such niceties might already be considered to be 'taken as read' as part of our presupposed epistemological commitment to using Agda in the first place... ;-)

Comment: Your comment about `inv-z≤n {.zero} (z≤n)` and "forced" bindings really clarified things for me! Is there a way to get the type checker to show this or something similar explicitly somewhere once the proof is written?

Answer (score 2):

The way I think of *why* this is true is as follows: the only inequality of the form `m ≤ zero` in the definition of the the relation `≤` is `zero ≤ zero`, or equivalently `z≤n {0}`. So, if we assume `m ≤ zero`, we "must" have `m ≡ 0`.

```
data _≤_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  z≤n : {n : ℕ} → zero ≤ n
  s≤s : {m n : ℕ} → m ≤ n → suc m ≤ suc n
```

And if you start writing your proof like this

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n = ?
```

Then `C-c C-l` transforms it into

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n = {!   !}
```

with goal

```
?0 : m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
```

Then `C-c C-,` gives you the goal and context:

```
m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
m : ℕ   (not in scope)
```

So this confirms that you have to define a function `m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero`. And indeed `C-c C-r`

will produce

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n = λ x → {!   !}
```

with goal and context

```
m ≡ zero
x : m ≤ zero
m : ℕ   (not in scope)
```

At this stage, the best I can suggest is to change your definition to

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n x = ?
```

(which may on fact be a more natural starting point than the one I initially suggested) and do `C-c C-l` and `C-c C-,` again. Then you get:

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n x = {!   !}
```

with goal and context

```
m ≡ zero
x : m ≤ zero
m : ℕ   (not in scope)
```

Now the trick is to recall that `m ≤ zero` is an inductive type, so you can use `C-c C-c` and case split on `x`to distinguish between possible cases (this could not be done when `x` was only a local variable). And then you get only one possible case, namely `z≤n`, for the reasons explained at the beginning of this post. Now your definition looks like this:

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n z≤n = {!   !}
```

with goal and context (after doing `C-c C-,` again)

```
zero ≡ zero
```

and then it is clear that `refl` will close this goal. And indeed `C-c C-r` gives you:

```
inv-z≤n : {m : ℕ} → m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero
inv-z≤n z≤n = refl
```

with goal and context

```
*All Done*
```

I don't know any way to make the proof of `m ≤ zero → m ≡ zero` explicit besides the case split / pattern matching described above.

Comment: A question that came up when I wrote my answer is whether there is a way to transform `inv-z≤n = λ x → {!   !}` into `inv-z≤n x = {!   !}` without manually adding the `x` and removing the `λ x → `? Any pointers would be appreciated!